# American Airlines Delay Responsibility for overstaying 1 day VWP

Tags: air-travel, us-visa-waiver-program, overstaying, delays

Will American Airlines take responsibility for overstaying 1 day of VWP due to a delay in a connecting flight?

Comment: Are the flights part of the same ticket?

Comment: Airlines’ terms & conditions generally state that visas and other entry requirements in general are the passenger’s responsibility

Comment: @Traveller while you are correct regarding the airlines responsibility, there may be another viable answer to this question which the OP may instead welcome - in general if the passenger is unable to leave the country due to no fault of their own (eg delayed/cancelled flight), US immigration tends to be fairly accommodating in terms of visas.  My question was basically trying to determine if the OP was in a position to mitigate the issues of a missed connection, which would look more favourably on them than if they didn't.

Comment: @Moo Indeed, that’s why I only commented rather than answered, and upvoted your own comment.

Comment: How would they “take responsibility”? IMHO it’s the traveller’s responsibility to include enough margin in their travel plans to account for any delays and cancellations.

Comment: If the US decides to [throw the book at you](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/throw_the_book_at) because of the overstay, there will be very little that the airline could do to stop that.  Fortunately, they probably won't.

Comment: No business will take responsibility for consequential losses because there's no way to quantify them. Your flight is delayed so AA might credit you with a few dollars for your trouble. They're not going to take responsibility for your relationship with CBP, or make good on that million-dollar contract you missed the meeting to sign, or... It's a bad idea to plan a trip so close to the wire for this very reason.

Comment: You may also want to check your I94 record online. Depending on the circumstances, it’s not completely impossible they recorded the original departure date rather than the actual one.